# PHP problemas com Barras

Tags: php

Galera dei uma pesquisada mas não encontrei algo assertivo quanto ao erro que estou tendo.
Estou fazendo o a inserção de um arquivo csv na base de dados, porém a barra invertida tem bugado muito a separação de colunas, um dado da coluna c se une com a colune b.

Segue código;

**PHP**

```
<?php
$file = "arquivo.csv"
if (($base = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($base, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
   //aqui realizo as correções de campos e insert na base utilizando $data[0], $data[1]...e assim por diante.
  }
}
```

**RESULTADO COM ERRO**

A falha acontece com alguns registros em especifico.
O retorno do `$sql` é algo parecido com isso:

```
INSERT INTO (coluna1, coluna2, coluna3, coluna4, coluna5)
VALUES ("13", "asuahsuhas /";1435789;Nome do Usuario"","")
```

Um exemplo de campo que está dando erro:

```
Uheuehuehwueheue /\
```

Me parece que a barra invertida quebra  a tabulação, e pelo entendi haveria a necessidade de corrigir isso na leitura do arquivo e não via replace.
*OBS: Não consigo mexer base do arquivo .csv

Alguma dica ?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas acho que isso pode ser resolvido colocando uma barra invertida antes desta barra, ficando assim: `"asuahsuhas \/"`, deve ser possível utilizando o `str_replace`

Comment: Mas o replace não muda o fato de que o php leu 3 campos em 1 só eu precisava corrigir na leitura do arquivo, mas não sei como.

Comment: Vi que o fgetcsv tem um escape $escape = "\" mas ainda não consegui entender a utilização

Comment: existe diferença entre as barras, a "\" é um, digamos, caractere especial, ele deixa 'escapar'(printar) outros caracteres que especiais, como no regex, se quiser pegar um parenteses sem que ele seja utilizado para limitar um grupo, já a outra barra é um caractere comum, qual dos dois você tem no seu CSV? caso tenha "\", você deverá mudar esse escape par algum caractere que não tem no CSV (não tenho certeza, mas pode ser possível deixá-lo vazio).

Comment: um exemplo é se tiver um "\t" no seu arquivo, ele vai pular uma linha. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: no csv vem barra "/" e a invertida "\" estão quebrando as colunas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui entender como funciona, mas substituindo o fgetcsv pelos dados abaixo resolveu:

`($data = fgetcsv($base, 0, ';' , '"' , '"')`

Assim leitura do csv arquivo não quebra, após isso só fiz a substituição das barras.

```
<?php
  $file = "arquivo.csv"
  if (($base = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {

     while (($data = fgetcsv($base, 0, ';' , '"' , '"')) !== FALSE) {
       $data = str_replace('/', '', $data);
       $data = str_replace('\\', '', $data);
       //aqui realizo as correções de campos e insert na base utilizando $data[0], $data[1]...e assim por diante.
     }
  }
```

Resolvido até então.